# Calling function in parent class and accessing parent self

Tags: python, class

In my main window I set a variable `self.print_this`. I then call another class `PhotoViewer` and then in that class I call a function from my main window. In that function I try to print the self.print_this but I get the following error: `AttributeError: PhotoViewer` object has no attribute `print_this`
How do I access the `self` of the window class or avoid sending the self of `PhotoViewer` to the `printfromwindow` function?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint, QRect, QSize, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QRubberBand, QColorDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QPen
import sys

class PhotoViewer(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPoint)
    rectChanged = pyqtSignal(QRect)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PhotoViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        Window.printfromwindow(self)

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.print_this='test'
        PhotoViewer(self)

    def printfromwindow(self):
        print(self.print_this)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `Window.printfromwindow(self)` should **not** have the `self` argument, also, it's not referencing an instance of the `Window` class.

Comment: Okay I removed the self, how do I get it to reference the Window class.

Comment: see my answer below, hope it is explained well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but perhaps something like this. Note that in your code, you're calling methods of the `Window` and `PhotoViewer` classes but not constructing an instance of those classes.

1. You need to instantiate and retain those instances within their parent/child class instances, if you want to be able to reference their methods/properties.
2. As noted in my comment above, `Window.printfromwindow(self)` should not have the `self` argument (and should instead refer to `<instance of Window>.printfromwindow()`.

In the `Window` constructor, I assign `self.viewer` an instance of the `PhotoViewer` class and pass `self` (which is a `Window` instance) as the `parent` argument to its constructor.

Then, in `PhotoViewer` class constructor, we do `self.window = parent` which should allow you to call `self.window.printfromwindow()`:

```
class PhotoViewer(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPoint)
    rectChanged = pyqtSignal(QRect)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PhotoViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.window = parent  # relates the "parent" Window instance to this "child" PhotoViewer instance
        self.window.printfromwindow()  # calls the printfromwindow method from the "parent" Window instance

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.print_this='test'
        self.viewer = PhotoViewer(self)  # creates an instance of PhotoViewer class as an attribute of this Window instance

    def printfromwindow(self):
        print(self.print_this)
```

If you want to make this more readily available (i.e., not just from within the constructor of `PhotoViewer`) then assign the `Window.printfromwindow` to an attribute of the `PhotoViewer`, like:

```
class PhotoViewer(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPoint)
    rectChanged = pyqtSignal(QRect)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PhotoViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.window = parent  # relates the "parent" Window instance to this "child" PhotoViewer instance
        self.printfromwindow = self.window.printfromwindow  

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.print_this='test'
        self.viewer = PhotoViewer(self)  # creates an instance of PhotoViewer class as an attribute of this Window instance

    def printfromwindow(self):
        print(self.print_this)
```

Since functions are first-level objects in python, you can do this:

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.viewer.printfromwindow()
```

Answer (score 0):

To access a parent class you need to pass the parent class through the function. `def printfromwindow(Window)`. Then you inherit all of the attributes from the parent class. You can also modify a subclass with `super().__init__` to add changes to the sub classes without effecting the parent class